# (Edited) I am having an issue with my application not giving in-game currency

Tags: javascript, react-native

[Edited - Last time I forgot to add the code]

So i'm having an issue with my code not adding in-game currency to the user after they buy a product. All the internal testing and money work is well- the purchase goes through and the money is received. There is just an issue with adding the currency, which are in this case emblems, to the user. Unfortunately my friend wrote this code who no longer works on the project and I'm not very familiar with any of this, as I normally do UI stuff. Please let me know if I should upload any other images or provide any further information.

I'm not sure how far along it gets in the code before it breaks, but what I do know is using a button for testing and adding the same asyncstorage.getitem and setitem works when an onpress for a button. Again, I am very unfamiliar with all of this stuff so let me know what I need to provide to help.

This code works:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('emblems').then(value =>{AsyncStorage.setItem('emblems', '10')})
```

This code doesn't work

```
<BuyBox Price='$0.99' EN='1 Emblem' onPress={async () => {
                    if (this.state.offerings != null) {
                        const pkg = this.state.offerings.emblems.availablePackages.find(offering => offering.identifier === 'ispy_1_emblems');
                        if (pkg) {
                            const {customerInfo, productIdentifier} = await Purchases.purchasePackage(pkg);
                            if (typeof customerInfo.entitlements.active.my_entitlement_identifier !== "undefined") {
                                console.log("purchase successful")
                                AsyncStorage.getItem('emblems').then(value => {
                                       if (value == null){
                                        AsyncStorage.setItem('emblems', '1');
                                    } else {
                                        AsyncStorage.setItem('emblems', (Number(value) + 1).toString());
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }}/>
```

Comment: please remove the links to the images of text ... replace them with the text

Answer (score 0):

You forget to mention which library you using.
I'm guessing you're using **Revenuecat react-native-purchases**, you can print **pkg** in console to see many details including currency

`const {customerInfo, productIdentifier} = await Purchases.purchasePackage(pkg);`

Comment: I am using revenue cat, that is correct. But forgive me if I am wrong, but what do the packages have to do with the adding of the currency? I thought it was the AsyncStorage stuff, as far as I know the RevenueCat has to do with the money and the name of the package, which are all correct. If I am wrong, should I make a console.log of the the pkg? And what should I look for to be wrong?

Comment: Actually currency shouldn't be fixed as it shown below here **$0.99**, currency should be following each country currency based on user location, what is the app target? is it specific to one country? in that pkg it will show currency based on user location.

    <BuyBox Price='$0.99' EN='1 Emblem' onPress={async () => {

Comment: I think there was a slight mis-understanding; I am talking about the emblems being added not the currency of the users' country. For instance in games that would be gold you can buy, that is what is not being added.

Answer (score 0):

use **try** to test it, I think it will giving error for the first time when there's no value on emblems

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("emblems");
  if (value !== null) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("emblems", (Number(value) + 1).toString());
  } else {
    //first time in
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("emblems", "1"); //Set  1
  }
} catch (e) {
  // error reading value
  await AsyncStorage.setItem("emblems", "1");
}
```